# how to display random image using C# in application development of windows phone 7?

Tags: image, windows-phone-7

I am making an application in which when the user will start the application a random image will be displayed(all this images will be along with this app).
please help me how to get through it?

Answer (score 1):

pseudocode

1. int imgcount = number of images available
2. int ndx = random number between 0 and imgcount-1
3. display image[ndx]

Comment: but sir where should i store the images to display them...please

Comment: You do need to add them to the Visual Studio Resources for your project.

Answer (score 0):

You should include that images into the solution (make sure that they are marker as 'Copy if newer' or 'Copy always'). That make the images are copied into xap file and moved to the user device when he install the application.

The randomization process is quite simple: use [Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) class to generate random integer and depending on that integer choose one of the photos.